# submodules and endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Lets consider $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

a) Find the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

b) Determine $End_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})$, where $End_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})$ denotes the set of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I didn't find any examples that was similar to this one, so I don't know where to start. I'll appreciate any suggestions or similar examples, thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb Z$-modules are just abelian groups.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Z modules are just abelian groups.

An endomorphism of a cyclic group is determined by the image of a generator.